# GStreamer 1.0 autovideosink Could not initialise Xv output

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer, gst-launch-1.0

I have my C code which uses GStreamer.I have just installed gst-launch-1.0 on my  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS,after that i verified that i have a working installation by command

> gst-inspect-1.0 fakesrc

which print out a bunch of information about this.Also checked with

> gst-launch-1.0 -v fakesrc silent=false num-buffers=3 ! fakesink
>   silent=false

command it produces output.But when i try to test video displayed by running

> gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

it is giving me below logs

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libEGL warning: DRI2: xcb_connect failed
libEGL warning: DRI2: xcb_connect failed
libEGL warning: GLX: failed to load GLX
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage: Could not initialise Xv output
Additional debug info:
xvimagesink.c(1765): gst_xvimagesink_open (): /GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage:
Could not open display (null)
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

please HELP.

Comment: Could be a permission issue with your current user and accessing video hardware?

Comment: i am not a super user,i tried sudo gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink,even then same issue.Do i need to Login as superuser?

Comment: Could also be that the system has no hardware acceleration support activated. maybe missing or wrong gpu driver?

Comment: Are you running this on that ubuntu computer directly (i.e. are you sitting in front of it) or are you trying this over ssh connection?

Comment: I am trying it over ssh connection using Putty.